# Cant move textview up in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I got such a weird issue.

Im busy working with the image below:

[image: Cart counter]

The issue is that I need to get the TextView("9" in the image) to move upwards. This image + textview is in the tool bar.

In the layout file I can move the image up and down as i please, but it gets cut off because of the lack of space in the toolbar. So what happens is the cart icon gets cut off on the bottom if I move the image downwards.

I need that counter to move upwards. I have tried below on the TextView:

> android:paddingBottom="9dp"

and

> android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"

but neither of them move the textview.

Please see layout file below:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/counterPanel"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cartCountIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cart_dark"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cartCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_6"
    tools:text="7"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how I am using this layout in the code:

```
public static Drawable buildCartDrawable(Context context, int count, boolean isCartLight) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cart_counter_menu_item, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartCount);
    ImageView cartIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartCountIcon);
    int backgroundImageId;

    if (isCartLight) {
      textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
      backgroundImageId = R.drawable.cart_empty;
      if (count > 0) {
        backgroundImageId = R.drawable.cart;
      }
    } else {
      backgroundImageId = R.drawable.cart_empty_dark;
      if (count > 0) {
        backgroundImageId = R.drawable.cart_dark;
      }
    }
    cartIcon.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

    if (count == 0) {
      textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (count < 10) {
      textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
    } else {
      textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 11);
    }

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, cartIcon.getMeasuredWidth(), cartIcon.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return new BitmapDrawable(BobeApplication.getAppContext().getResources(), bitmap);
  }
```

I need the TextView to move up about 3/4dp at most but it seems to stay centered in the toolbar and I can't see a fix for this.

Comment: try to remove android:layout_alignParentTop="true", and play with the top margin as well, maybe the item doenst have space to go up

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout. To textView add layout_gravity="center" and maybe try add marginBottom

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/counterPanel"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cartCountIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cart_dark"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cartCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_6"
    tools:text="7"/>

</FrameLayout>
```